# JavaScript array of huge data (500K record) taking time to search and add

Tags: javascript, jquery

My function is called in loop which returns more than 500k record.
I have to insert that record in a JavaScript array. Before inserting records  to array need to check existing array has duplicate records or not. If the record is duplicate then exclude the record.
When array size increases the run time of the function is very high. Please suggest me a way to optimize search.

```
function AddDataToArray(StdName, currObjectSTD, bufferObject, attributes, bufferSTD) {

    var result = false;
    
    
        var existingObjects = AllDataArray.find(item => {
               item.OBJECTID==attributes.OBJECTID
                && item.name == bufferObject.name
                && item.StdName == StdName);
        });

        if (existingObjects.length == 0) {          
            var currentObject = {
                "ID": 0,
                "currObjectSTD": currObjectSTD,
                "color": bufferObject.color,
                "name": bufferObject.name,
                "attributes": attributes,
                "StdName": StdName,
                "objectID": objectID,
                "bufferSTD": bufferSTD,
                "shape": null,
                "shapeSTD": null
            };
            AllDataArray.push(currentObject);
            result = true;
        }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: It looks like a for loop would give you the most performance on an array of this size, based on this bench-marking https://nikitahl.com/how-to-find-an-item-in-a-javascript-array/

However, as others will likely tell you, you're much better off querying this data when it's contained in a database which has been properly indexed. You can optimize all you want with the client side javascript, but you will never get the performance you desire going about it this way I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

As a speedup workaround I suggest you coming up with some kind of hash map based on your array to avoid continuos looping through array

```
const dataHashMap = _(AllDataArray)
 .keyBy(item => `${item.OBJECTID}-${item.name}-${item.StdName}`)
 .mapValues(() => true)
 .value();

 var existingObjects = dataHashMap[`${attributes.OBJECTID}-${bufferObject.name}-${StdName}`]
```

or alternative solution

```
let groupedDataHashMap = {}

AllDataArray.forEach(item => {
  _.set(
      groupedDataHashMap,
      [
        item.OBJECTID,
        item.name,
        item.StdName
      ],
      true
  )
})

var existingObjects = _.get(
  groupedDataHashMap,
  [
     attributes.OBJECTID,
     bufferObject.name,
     StdName
  ],
  false
)
```

I used lodash methods but if you prefer using native array/object methods you can come up with your own implementation, but the idea is the same

P.S you need to create this hash map once you fetched your array and populate it with new items simultaneously with your array to keep it up-to-date with your array